# How can I remove enclosing brackets from a line?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Given a line like this: `"hello my (name) is (user)`, how can I remove all `'()'` using *sed*?

What I'm currently doing is highlighting the line using visual block, and then `:s/(//g` and again for `)`. Is there a way to remove both `(, )` in one *sed* command?

My end goal is `"hello my name is user"`

Comment: Is the goal to remove all parentheses, or only matched pairs of them? For example, if a line had a `(` but no corresponding `)`, what should happen? Or what if it has a closing parenthesis before the opening one, like `)(`?

Comment: I use this on a very limited controlled input, where the only parentheses are paired

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `tr  -d '()' <infile` too.

Answer (score 13):

You can use character class `[()]` as Regex pattern, and replace the pattern with empty string to remove them:

```
sed 's/[()]//g'
```

So:

```
% sed 's/[()]//g' <<<"hello my (name) is (user)"
hello my name is user
```

`g` modifier does the operation on all matches, otherwise `sed` will stop after the first match.

Answer (score 4):

You can save the bracket content in a group and replace by that:

```
sed 's/(\([^)]*\))/\1/g'
```

This saves everything inside the brackets (`[^)]*` simply matches everything except `)`) in group 1 and replaces the whole bracket by it. Doing that `g`lobally means to do it for every pair of brackets in the line.

#### Usage example

```
$ echo '"hello my (name) is (user)"' | sed 's/(\([^)]*\))/\1/g'
"hello my name is user"
```

Comment: Why capture a group if all you want is to remove a character? Even if you don't want to use a character class, you could simply do `sed 's/(//g; s/)//g'` More importantly, this fails on input like `((hello)` or `(foo` or `(a((b())d))`.

Comment: @terdon Just removing characters fails on something like `((test)`, but OP asks how to remove *enclosing* brackets!

Comment: Even if you only limit to that, it still fails on ` (a (foo) ab)`.